# Best way to get the difference of Pandas DatetimeIndex series in days?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a series of pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex, which is basically weekdays of 2016. Is there any easy/elegant way of finding out the sequential difference in days of the series? Just like .diff() does for an integer or float DataFrame column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ds = pd.date_range("2016-01-01","2016-12-31",freq='B')

# I was hoping for something like this:
ds.diff().days

# this gives me what I want, but it is ugly and unintuitive
np.diff(ds) / 86400000000000
```

I also thought about `np.diff(ds.date)` but it gives me an ndarray of datetime.timedelta, and i don't know how to transform it into an integer array/series without a for-loop.

Comment: `ds.to_series().diff()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
In [154]: ds.to_series().diff()
Out[154]:
2016-01-01      NaT
2016-01-04   3 days
2016-01-05   1 days
2016-01-06   1 days
2016-01-07   1 days
2016-01-08   1 days
2016-01-11   3 days
2016-01-12   1 days
2016-01-13   1 days
2016-01-14   1 days
2016-01-15   1 days
2016-01-18   3 days
2016-01-19   1 days
2016-01-20   1 days
2016-01-21   1 days
2016-01-22   1 days
2016-01-25   3 days
2016-01-26   1 days
2016-01-27   1 days
2016-01-28   1 days
2016-01-29   1 days
2016-02-01   3 days
2016-02-02   1 days
2016-02-03   1 days
2016-02-04   1 days
              ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need add [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) if need numeric output:

```
print (ds.to_series().diff().dt.days)
```

```
2016-01-01    NaN
2016-01-04    3.0
2016-01-05    1.0
2016-01-06    1.0
2016-01-07    1.0
2016-01-08    1.0
2016-01-11    3.0
2016-01-12    1.0
2016-01-13    1.0
2016-01-14    1.0
2016-01-15    1.0
2016-01-18    3.0
2016-01-19    1.0
2016-01-20    1.0
2016-01-21    1.0
2016-01-22    1.0
2016-01-25    3.0
2016-01-26    1.0
2016-01-27    1.0
2016-01-28    1.0
2016-01-29    1.0
2016-02-01    3.0
2016-02-02    1.0
2016-02-03    1.0
2016-02-04    1.0
2016-02-05    1.0
2016-02-08    3.0
2016-02-09    1.0
2016-02-10    1.0
2016-02-11    1.0

2016-11-21    3.0
2016-11-22    1.0
2016-11-23    1.0
2016-11-24    1.0
2016-11-25    1.0
2016-11-28    3.0
2016-11-29    1.0
2016-11-30    1.0
2016-12-01    1.0
2016-12-02    1.0
2016-12-05    3.0
2016-12-06    1.0
2016-12-07    1.0
2016-12-08    1.0
2016-12-09    1.0
2016-12-12    3.0
2016-12-13    1.0
2016-12-14    1.0
2016-12-15    1.0
2016-12-16    1.0
2016-12-19    3.0
2016-12-20    1.0
2016-12-21    1.0
2016-12-22    1.0
2016-12-23    1.0
2016-12-26    3.0
2016-12-27    1.0
2016-12-28    1.0
2016-12-29    1.0
2016-12-30    1.0
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```